RegionPlot3D not showing thin areas
I am trying to visualize a condition with the function RegionPlot3D.
I know that the area should look like this:

That is, for every v there is some orange area.
However, some areas are too thin, so mathematica has not shown them and showed this instead:

Is there a way I can make mathematica show all conditions (like the first image)?
Thank you!
RegionPlot3D[(-a^2 + 2 a c + a^2 c - c^2 - c^3)/(a c - c^2 - c^3) > v > 1/Root[
 a^2 - a c - a^2 c + 2 a c^2 - 
   c^3 + (-a^2 + a^3 + a c + 3 a^2 c - a^3 c - 5 a c^2 + 
      2 c^3) #1 + (2 a^3 - 5 a^2 c - a^3 c + 4 a c^2 + 2 a^2 c^2 -
       c^3 - a c^3) #1^2 + (-a^3 + 2 a^2 c + a^3 c - a c^2 - 
      2 a^2 c^2 + a c^3) #1^3 &, 3] && 1 > c > a > 0, {v, .001,1}, {c, .001, .999}, {a, .001, .999}]


Please include Mathematica code for a minimal example that would replicate the plot shown in the OP. Thanks.

@Syed Edited. Thank you for reminding!

NIntegrate[  Boole[(-a^2 + 2 a c + a^2 c - c^2 - c^3)/(a c - c^2 - c^3) > v >      1/Root[a^2 - a c - a^2 c + 2 a c^2 -          c^3 + (-a^2 + a^3 + a c + 3 a^2 c - a^3 c - 5 a c^2 +             2 c^3) #1 + (2 a^3 - 5 a^2 c - a^3 c + 4 a c^2 +             2 a^2 c^2 - c^3 - a c^3) #1^2 + (-a^3 + 2 a^2 c + a^3 c -             a c^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 + a c^3) #1^3 &, 3] && 1 > c > a > 0 &&   a >= 0], {a, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 6,  PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] results in 0.0662847, confirming the set under cosideration is a solid.

As usually, WorkingPrecision -> 12, PlotPoints -> 75 help.
RegionPlot3D[(-a^2 + 2 a c + a^2 c - c^2 - c^3)/(a c - c^2 - c^3) > 
   v > 1/Root[ a^2 - a c - a^2 c + 2 a c^2 - 
   c^3 + (-a^2 + a^3 + a c + 3 a^2 c - a^3 c - 5 a c^2 + 
      2 c^3) #1 + (2 a^3 - 5 a^2 c - a^3 c + 4 a c^2 + 2 a^2 c^2 -
       c^3 - a c^3) #1^2 + (-a^3 + 2 a^2 c + a^3 c - a c^2 - 
      2 a^2 c^2 + a c^3) #1^3 &, 3] && 1 > c > a > 0, {v, .001,1}, 
{c, .001, .999}, {a, .001, .999}, WorkingPrecision -> 12,  PlotPoints -> 75]


and a several warnings caused by that Root[] involves complex numbers.

@The downvoter: What is incorrect in my answer? It is unfair to down vote without  any explaining comment.

A better equality plots.
Expression for eq and r are taken from OP code and then they are used to make equations in a slightly different form. The equations are used in ContourPlot3D instead of RegionPlot3D used in OP.
eq = v == (-a^2 + 2 a c + a^2 c - c^2 - c^3)/(a c - c^2 - c^3);

r = Root[a^2 - a c - a^2 c + 2 a c^2 - 
     c^3 + (-a^2 + a^3 + a c + 3 a^2 c - a^3 c - 5 a c^2 + 
        2 c^3) #1 + (2 a^3 - 5 a^2 c - a^3 c + 4 a c^2 + 2 a^2 c^2 - 
        c^3 - a c^3) #1^2 + (-a^3 + 2 a^2 c + a^3 c - a c^2 - 
        2 a^2 c^2 + a c^3) #1^3 &, 3];

nr = Root[r[[1]]@(1/x) // Factor // Numerator, x, 2];

eq1 = a == 
   SolveValues[
     v == (-a^2 + 2 a c + a^2 c - c^2 - c^3)/(a c - c^2 - c^3), 
     a][[2]];
eq2 = v == nr;

ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@eq1, {v, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}]
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@eq2, {v, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}]
Show[%%, %]



Update:
@C.K wanted to see the thickness of the region (see his comment).
The thickness is depicted by slicing the region with planes c=1, c=0.9, ... c=0 for step s=0.1.
The first image is for s=1/10, the second image for s=1/100.
In the code we have to take care of special limit case c=1 - hence the Which and special limit case c=0 - hence the Append.
s = 1/10;
plots = Append[
   Table[ContourPlot[
     Which[c == 1, {v == (2 - 2 a)/(2 - a), v == 1 - a}, 
       True, {v == (
         a^2 - 2 a c - a^2 c + c^2 + c^3)/(-a c + c^2 + c^3), 
        v == Root[
          a^3 - 2 a^2 c - a^3 c + a c^2 + 2 a^2 c^2 - 
            a c^3 + (-2 a^3 + 5 a^2 c + a^3 c - 4 a c^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 + 
               c^3 + a c^3) #1 + (a^2 - a^3 - a c - 3 a^2 c + a^3 c + 
               5 a c^2 - 2 c^3) #1^2 + (-a^2 + a c + a^2 c - 2 a c^2 +
                c^3) #1^3 &, 2]}] // Evaluate, {v, 0, 1}, {a, 0, c}, 
     ContourStyle -> Blend[ColorData[97] /@ {1, 4}, c], 
     PlotPoints -> 50], {c, 1, s, -s}], 
   ContourPlot[a == 0, {v, 0, 1}, {a, -0.01, 1}, 
    ContourStyle -> Blend[ColorData[97] /@ {1, 4}, 0], 
    PlotPoints -> 50]];

Show@plots

Manipulate[
 Show[plots[[n]], PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {n, 1, Length[plots], 1}]





The results of NIntegrate[  Boole[(-a^2 + 2 a c + a^2 c - c^2 - c^3)/(a c - c^2 - c^3) > v >      1/Root[a^2 - a c - a^2 c + 2 a c^2 -          c^3 + (-a^2 + a^3 + a c + 3 a^2 c - a^3 c - 5 a c^2 +             2 c^3) #1 + (2 a^3 - 5 a^2 c - a^3 c + 4 a c^2 +             2 a^2 c^2 - c^3 - a c^3) #1^2 + (-a^3 + 2 a^2 c + a^3 c -    a c^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 + a c^3) #1^3 &, 3] && 1 > c > a > 0 &&  a >= 0], {a, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 4,   PrecisionGoal -> 4, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] is 0.066437. This shows the set under consideration is a solid., not a surface.

We see  inequalities in (-a^2 + 2 a c + a^2 c - c^2 - c^3)/(a c - c^2 - c^3) > v > 1/Root[  a^2 - a c - a^2 c + 2 a c^2 -     c^3 + (-a^2 + a^3 + a c + 3 a^2 c - a^3 c - 5 a c^2 +        2 c^3) #1 + (2 a^3 - 5 a^2 c - a^3 c + 4 a c^2 + 2 a^2 c^2 -        c^3 - a c^3) #1^2 + (-a^3 + 2 a^2 c + a^3 c - a c^2 -        2 a^2 c^2 + a c^3) #1^3 &, 3] && 1 > c > a > 0.

In view of the above is  your result not a fake?

@user64494 Question is about depicting the object not about any integral. 3D objects are perfectly well depicted by boundary surfaces by which they are enclosed.

Sorry, I don't imagine a solid which boundary consists of the three surfaces you has drawn. Can you kindly explain it, uniting the surfaces?

@azerbajdzan Thank you for your input. I think the plots are very helpful. I would like to know if there is a way the plot can also show how thick the area is because for this function I found it very difficult to know the size of the yellow area in the middle.

I tried removing Mesh and making the shape translucent and then use the "If" function to selectively show areas based on the difference between (-a^2 + 2 a c + a^2 c - c^2 - c^3)/(a c - c^2 - c^3) and the Root function, hoping to then combine the different plots and make something like a contour map. But, I have not been successful.

@C.K I have made an update to depict the thickness of your region.

Thank you very much! But I am not familiar with those commands. Could you briefly explain how one can understand the output (such as what n and s are), please? Thanks a lot!

@C.K Search the documentation for commands you do not understand. It is explained in the answer what the output represents.
